# Problems with doing calculus on Interpolating functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, interpolation, plotting

The following is my code:

```
a := 3.24077*10^-20 (* km \[Rule] Mpc *)
b := 3.16888*10^-14 (* s \[Rule] MYear *)
c := a/b*(2.99792*10^5) (*Mpc/ MYear*)
H0 := a/b*71 (*1/MYear*)
G := a^3/b^2*6.67398*10^-20 (*Mpc^3/(Kg*MYear^2)*)

\[Rho]crit1 := 3/(8 \[Pi]*G)*(H0)^2 
    M1[r_] := (4 \[Pi] )/3*\[Rho]crit1*(r)^3 
    E1[r_] := 0
    ScaleFactor = 
      NDSolve[{Sqrt[R[r, t]] (D[R[r, t], t]) == 
          Sqrt[(2*G*M1[r])/c + 2 c*E1[r]*R[r, t]], R[r, 0] == r/1000}, 
        R, {r, 1, 10000}, {t, 1, 10000}] // FullSimplify;
    Plot3D[Evaluate[R[r, t] /. %], {r, 1, 10000}, {t, 1, 10000}]
    ParticleHorizon[r_, g_] := 
     NIntegrate[(c Sqrt[1 + 2 E1[r]])/
      D[Evaluate[R[r1, t] /. ScaleFactor, r1 -> r], r], {t, 0, g}]
    Plot3D[ParticleHorizon[r,g], {r, 1, 10}, {g, 1, 10}]
```

My problem is that once I've solved the differential equation to get `R[r,t]` (which it solves without a problem, giving me an interpolating function), I have trouble differentiating the result with respect to `r`, to be used in my `ParticleHorizon` function. I think it might be because the differential operator uses `DSolve` or `NDSolve` intrinsically.

Here, `a,b,c,f,G` and `lambda` are constants and `M1[r]` is a boundary condition that we need to solve the differential equation for `R[r,t]`. `E1[r]` has been set to 0 for now for simplicity.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Also, the rule to change `r1->r` was just me trying to see if it works, which it doesn't...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, welcome! Try to find a minimal example that illustrate your problem, so that it shows your effort, is less work for the people trying to help you, and is more general and helps future visitors more

Comment: Hiya, sorry about that. I've condensed the problem down a bit...thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You need to provide numerical values for all the constants too.

Comment: done! sorry about that too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
ParticleHorizon[r_, g_] := 
   NIntegrate[(c Sqrt[1 + 2 E1[r]])/Evaluate[D[R[r, t] /. ScaleFactor[[1]]], r], {t, 0, g}]

ListPlot3D[
        Flatten[Table[{r, g, ParticleHorizon[r, g]}, {r, 1, 10}, {g, 1, 10}], 1], 
        ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", Mesh -> True, 
        MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.8], Specularity[White, 50]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I used `ListPlot3D` just because it is faster than `Plot3D[]`

Comment: as a side note, you could also use `NDSolveValue` that would avoid that `... /. ScaleFactor[[1]]` business.

Comment: @ruebenko Not me :) ... still on v.8

Comment: ah, OK, then as an idea for the OP, and maybe a small incentive to upgrade ;-)